# AngularJS directive for storing DOM elements and redirecting on form submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, attributes, pug

I am getting into `AngularJS`, and I've been trying to understand directives because they are pretty much mandatory if you want to work with the DOM (when using `AngularJS`, correct me if I'm wrong). So here is the scenario, I am trying to create a simple login system (I am actually using the `MEAN` stack - `MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS, NodeJS`). I'm not too worried about security (or otherwise less than perfect code) because I am just trying to learn how to use the frameworks. Here is the relevant code:

MemberModule.js:

```
var MemberModule = angular.module('MemberModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);

MemberModule.controller('MemberListController', function ($scope, $html)) {
  $scope.members = [];
  $scope.newMember = {
    done : false
  };

  $scope.doneFilter = { done : true };
  $scope.notDoneFilter = { done : false };

  //various methods...

});

MemberModule.directive('usernameDir', ['$interval', function($interval) {
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var newMember,
        timeoutId;


    function updateUsername() {
      element.text(scope.newMember.username);
    }

    scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
      format = value;
      updateTime();
    });

    element.on('$destroy', function() {
      $interval.cancel(timeoutId);
    });

    // start the UI update process; save the timeoutId for canceling
    timeoutId = $interval(function() {
      UpdateTime(); // update DOM
    }, 1000);
  }

  return {
    link: link
  };
});

MemberModule.directive('passwordDir', function () {
  // The above name 'myDirective' will be parsed out as 'my-directive'
  // for in-markup uses.
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      'sub' : '&ngSubmit'
    },
    template: 'home'
  }
});
```

As you can see above, I created the main `angular.module` and called it `MemberModule` - which gets referenced in my `HTML` (I am using jade templates - so by `HTML` I mean `layout.jade`). After that I created the `controller` with its various methods that I need. Finally, I created the directives which is what I need help with. I am trying to assign a DOM input element (in a form) to an object attribute, and then redirect (or render) a jade template (`home.jade`).

The relevant form HTML ('index.jade'):

```
extends layout

block content
  div.container(ng-controller="MemberListController", ng-init="setMembers( #{JSON.stringify(members)} )")
    h1 Welcome
    h2 Sign Up
    form(novalidate, ng-submit="addNewMember()")
      input( type="text", username-dir info="userdir")
      br
      input( type="password", password-dir info="passdir")
      br
      input( type="password" )
      br
      button.btn.btn-primary(class="sub", type="submit") Submit
    h2 Adding...
      span(username dir)
      span(password dir)
```

I am just pasting what I have so far so you can see where I am at in terms of progress. I am fully aware that my code is not functional as is - I am just looking for some help in pointing out what needs to go where to accomplish my goal. I realize that the two directives (while trying to attain the same goal) are not using the same style of directive code - this is just because of where I am at in terms of trying things. Again, my goal is (specifically for the username and password):

**I am trying to assign a DOM input element (in a form) to an object attribute, and then redirect (or render) a jade template (`home.jade`).**

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need both directives at all. Just use ng-model (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to bind your scope data to the input elements. Then use ng-submit to call a function in the controller.

Comment: @Julian Hollmann cool - can you show me how in an answer?

Comment: @JulianHollman checking out the link - I think I can figure it out from this - thanks so much - you can post an example for an answer if you want.

Comment: You are welcome. Another small hint: In my opinion, angular is intended for single page applications. What you are doing is a bit strange. You first render your templates in the backend and then you render them in the frontend again using angular.

Comment: @JulianHollmann yah - thanks for the hint - i kind of get that. It's also another question I have...do I use express' res.render somewhere? and then what do i do for angular? i can paste more code if you need it

Comment: @JulianHollmann also - i put "ng-model=userdir" in the input tag - what do I do next...still a little confused.

Comment: @JulianHollmann I guess an example would be helpful if you have the time

Comment: @JulianHollmann plus you get stack points if you submit an answer! lol

Comment: @JulianHollmann figured it out! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big ups to Julian Hollmann (check comments):

"You don't need both directives at all. Just use ng-model (docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to bind your scope data to the input elements. Then use ng-submit to call a function in the controller."

Bingo - thanks!